# php custom error message shown incorrectly

Tags: php, session

i'm working on a php assignment for log in function using .txt file instead of db, but i'm facing with some sort of problem here. supposedly the "invalid email or password" to be shown after a non exist details key in, but when the page load, the msg showed by default, below is my code

```
<?php
$lines= file("customers.txt");
$matchFound=false;

$errmsg = 'Invalid email or password';

for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++)
{
    if ($i!=0)
    {
        $line=trim($lines[$i]); 
        $cells=explode("\t",$line);
        $_SESSION['email'] = isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : null;
        $_SESSION['password'] = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

        if ($_SESSION['email']==$cells[2] && $_SESSION['password']==$cells[3])
        {
            $matchFound=true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if ($matchFound == true)
{
    header('Location: login2.php');
}
else 
{
    echo $errmsg;
}
?>
```

Comment: Try adding an `exit` after your `header()`

Comment: Hm by default it will appear according this code

Comment: You'll also need a `session_start` at the top of the code, if you're wanting to access `$_SESSION` variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're not checking if the user submitted the form input correctly. The value of `$matchFound` is `FALSE` by default, and the error message will always be displayed when the script is ran.

Specify a `name` attribute for your form submit button, and then add an `if` block to make sure the form was correctly submitted:

```
if (isset( $_POST['submitButton'] )) {
    # code...
}
```

That way, the code inside the `if` block won't be run if the user input wasn't received and you could avoid the error being displayed every time you load the page.

Also, you're missing the [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) statement at the top of your script. This is required if you want the sessions to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($matchFound == true)
{
    header('Location: login2.php');
}
else if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    echo $errmsg;
}
```

Also you need session_start to use $_SESSION array

Comment: alright, thanks =) , anyway, i got another php script on top of this, i put seesion start in there already =)